# how to make the generice data type accessable to clone() method

Tags: generics, linked-list, cloneable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NUam.png)
[image]

as shown in the figure 
there is an error at 32 line that says 
`Node<T>(Object)` is not defined because `clone()` returns an Object data Type

I tried to make another constructor that takes an Object data type then cast it

 
it removes the first error which lead me to another error which says
the clone() method is not visible 
 
however, i write this line "`T extends Cloneable`"
any solutions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general way to clone another object in Java. Some specific implementing classes may provide a public `clone()` method, but there is no guarantee that the type `T` has such a public `clone()` method.

In particular, the `Cloneable` interface does not provide a public `clone()` method; that may be your misunderstanding. The purpose of `Cloneable` is not as an interface of objects that provide a public cloning interface, but rather as a marker to indicate to the `Object.clone()` method (if that is used in the cloning process somehow) whether to throw an exception or not. There is no common base type in Java that indicates the presence of a public `clone()` method. (You can make such an interface if you wish, but it would only apply to your own types.)